# Parent item with xpath in qml/qt

Tags: xml, qt, xpath, qml

How do I get the parent for the current item in an xpath query in qml/qt ?
`fn:parent()` isn't implemented, `../` yes but doesn't work for me.
Seems like a `focus` problem.

xml example:

```
<groups>
  <group id="A">
    <item>bla</item>
    <item>blah</item>
  </group>
  <group id="B">
    <item>bla</item>
    <item>blah</item>
  </group>
  <group id="C">
    <item>bla</item>
    <item>blah</item>
  </group>
</groups>
```

The following XmlRole returns an empty string:

```
XmlListModel {
  query: "/groups/group/item"
  XmlRole { name: "group_id"; query: "../@id/string()" }
}
```

Comment: There is a bug reported for this: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-17588

Answer (score 1):

Where is the source tag that tell the model from where take the query?
You need to declare the source, your ID property is outside of  node. And have to declare the namespace used(for example http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom). So i think that your code have to be like:

```
XmlListModel {
  query: "/groups/group/"
  namespaceDeclarations: "declare namespace group=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom/\";"
  source: "url of your xml file"
  XmlRole { name: "group_id"; query: "../@id/string()" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath:

```
../@id
```

> The **`string(object?)`** function converts an object to a string as follows:
>
> - A node-set is converted to a string by returning the string-value of
>     the node in the node-set that is first in document order. If the
>     node-set is **empty**, an **empty** string is returned.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions

Comment: the `@id/string()` part is correct, the problem occurs only with `../`

Comment: @Giovanni, Did you try `../@id`? What it returns?

Comment: @Giovannni: @id/string() is a syntactically valid expression *only* in XPath 2.0. Are you sure the XPath processor you are using really supports XPath 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

```
../@id/string()
```

**This is invalid syntax in XPath 1.0**.

Are you sure you are using an XPath 2.0 engine?

**In XPath 1.0 use**:

`string(../@id`)

Or, if an expression that selects a node-set is required, then simply use:

```
../@id
```

Comment: What do you mean "neither work"? The XPath expressions are syntactically valid and evaluate to the wanted strings. If something "doesn't work" then it is in the way you use the results of evaluating these XPath expressions.

Comment: Is the way they are implemented in the qml/qt engine, I think

Comment: probably should report the bug then

Answer (score 0):

It does appear that you are missing the source tag.... the location of the xml file.
Although the other discussion regarding the query syntax is still relevant.